# How to make new contacts exported from an app to Phonebook as EDITABLE

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I have an application which has it's own sets of contacts which is coming from a server. I am exporting this contact to the native contacts database. So that i can access it from the phonebook. However, i want to make these contacts as editable in native app.

I am using account authenticator and syncadapter approach for this.

Below is my `sync-adapter` xml

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:supportsUploading="true"
    android:userVisible="true"
    android:accountType="com.example.myapp"
/>
```

Setting `android:supportsUploading="true"`

Also, exporting raw contacts and data fields as non-read only by setting below flag as **0**
`android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts.RAW_CONTACT_IS_READ_ONLY`
`android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts.DATA_IS_READ_ONLY`

Still i am not seeing option to edit my contacts in native app.
What's missing here?

Thanks in advance

[UPDATE]
I am using below code to check which account type is supported by contacts and is editable.

```
final SyncAdapterType[] syncs = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
for (SyncAdapterType sync : syncs) {
    Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter: " + sync.accountType);
    if (ContactsContract.AUTHORITY.equals(sync.authority)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter that supports contacts: " + sync.accountType);
        if (sync.supportsUploading()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter that supports contacts and is not read-only: " + sync.accountType);
            // we'll now get a list of all accounts under that accountType:
            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType(sync.accountType);
            for (Account account : accounts) {
               Log.d(TAG, account.type + " / " + account.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My apps account type is non-read only but still don't see an edit option. Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you need to do:

1. Implement a `SyncService` and declare it on `AndroidManifest`
2. create a `contacts.xml` file that will that the contact editor how to parse and edit contacts related to your account

See: 
https://github.com/xwiki-contrib/android-authenticator/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L81-L94
https://github.com/xwiki-contrib/android-authenticator/blob/master/app/src/main/res/xml/syncadapter.xml
https://github.com/xwiki-contrib/android-authenticator/blob/master/app/src/main/res/xml/contacts.xml

as examples.

Comment: Thankyou @marmor. The server i am synchronising with doesn't support more than 3 email per contacts. Also, it has certain limitation like phone of type WORK max allowed is 2. Can we set these rules in contacts.xml ? Also, what are the keywords which i need to use ? Any link/tutorial will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried something like this below https://github.com/arekolek/knurek/blob/master/client/knurek/res/xml/contacts.xml
but contacts editor doesn't follow the constraints.

Comment: download "google contacts" and check if their editor works well, if it does, it's a bug in your stock contacts app, if not, there's probably something you are not declaring correctly, try to install and play with the code at: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SampleSyncAdapter and see if that works for you

Comment: I think you are right it works well in Google contacts. But in my samsung native app. Doesn't work well.

Comment: Thanks man! i appreciate your help!
Just one more question though. I couldn't find any relevant documentation for EditSchema. How can we limit the occurence of a particular type. e.g- Phone type Mobile should be allowed max 2. can i do something like <Type type="mobile" maxOccur="2"/> ?

Comment: no idea... don't think it's possible actually, if you would add phone w/ type home, and then two mobiles, you could then change the type of the first one from home to mobile (never saw the type selection limited), and then you end up with 3 mobiles

Comment: RIght ! Also, how can we make my exported contact as private so that apps like facebook, whatsapp cannot read them ?

Comment: you can't, all contacts stored on android's contacts DB are available through ContactsContract APIs

Comment: servers like exchange has limit on type selection like it only allow 2 Home type phone number, 1 Mobile type etc. Since we cant put this limitation in the native contact editor. Does the sync adapter need to take care of it ?

Comment: Can we insert CONTACT_STRUCTURE tag dynamically into android manifest? Idea is to give users option to between read only or write(Editable) contacts.

Comment: or can we put some settings to make contacts editable or readonly?

Comment: i don't know if you can change the structure dynamically, but what you can probably do is implement multiple SyncAdapters with multiple structures and allow the user to select which sync adapter to use (you can mask it as a simple setting)

Comment: Is it possible if i mark a contact as read only, i will not be able to edit those contacts? There is a column in raw_contacts table

Comment: you can do it on the SyncAdapter level in syncadapter.xml - set `android:supportsUploading="false"`

Comment: But that will make all the contacts readable, if i want to make specific contacts readable then ?

Comment: Also, can i change supportUploading property dynamically using a setting ?

Comment: Hey @marmor, i really appreciate your help. i have couple of question i have been stuck on for long. can we connect on hangout or something so that i can ask you directly?

Comment: join me here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196980/how-to-make-new-contacts-exported-from-an-app-to-phonebook-as-editable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197025/discussion-between-alphaguy-and-marmor).

Comment: I tried `android:supportsUploading="false"` but this doesn't make my contacts readonly. Note: i have added a contact structure xml also, do i need to remove that as well ?